# Rails calculation logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner and I was wondering where should I put calculation like this in Rails and also how to display it:

```
@suplement.total_cost = @suplement.number_of_days * @suplement.daily_dosage_in_units * (@suplement.suplement_cost / @suplement.number_of_units)
```

Here's the table I'm referring to:

```
create_table "suplements", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name"
t.integer "number_of_units"
t.integer "daily_dosage_in_units"
t.float "suplement_cost"
t.float "total_cost"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "user_id"
t.integer "number_of_days"
end
```

While I was just trying this calculation in a view it calculated it correctly and displayed in `f.text_area :total_cost` but obviously that is not what I wanted. Here's how I wanted to put it but it shows everything except total_cost:

```
<div> Name: <%= suplement.name %></div>
<div> Number of units: <%= suplement.number_of_units %></div>
<div>Daily dosage in units: <%= suplement.daily_dosage_in_units %></div>
<div>Number of days: <%= suplement.number_of_days %></div>
<div>Supplement cost: <%= suplement.suplement_cost %></div>
<div>Total cost: <%= suplement.total_cost %></div>
```

Comment: "obviously that is not what I wanted" - no, this is not not obvious at all (what you want).

Comment: Obviously was referring to not having a result in text area because it's meant to be output of the calculation not the input. Can you help in any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the `total_attribute` in its class, Suplement. This way you have access to all the remaining attributes, and the total is a "calculated" one:

```
class Suplement < ApplicationRecord
  def total_cost
    suplement_over_units = suplement_cost / number_of_units
    dosage_per_days = number_of_days * daily_dosage_in_units
    dosage_per_days * suplement_over_units
  end
end
```

Just assigned some variables, as in your example, it'd be just accessing the attributes, as you can't access the `@suplement` variable:

```
def total_cost
  number_of_days * daily_dosage_in_units * (suplement_cost / number_of_units)
end
```

Comment: If it's what you wanted, then you can accept the answer @nusound.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just started here and until now I thought I wasn't allowed to click on anything. :) Thanks, again!